# Translation of "gesture driven" in mobile app context

Tags: traducción

So far only thing I can think of is "Impulsado por gestos", but that doesn't feel quite right. Any other suggestions, maybe a different approach that would give the same meaning?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe "Controlado por gestos" is a better translation. A driver does not impulse his truck, but controls it.

Comment: Marked as answer because I finally went with this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- gestual http://dle.rae.es/gestual
- manejo gestual (busca "Google apuesta por el manejo gestual de la PC")
- control gestual http://www.xataka.com/tag/control-gestual
- conducción gestual
- activado por gestos
- a base de gestos
- conducido por gestos
- manejado por gestos

Comment: Have you ever used or heard of anyone using "gestual"?

Comment: @AndreiD No. La verdad no se usa mucho verbalmente, en textos si la he visto, de todos modos verbalmente si se usa mucho la palabra "textual", entonces cuando tu uses "gestual" la gente de inmediato entendera a que te refieres.

Answer (score 0):

I will recomend: "control gestual" or "manejo gestual".